# Como salvar arquivo de uma pasta em outra?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tenho uma *listView* que exibe os arquivos de uma pasta externa (usb). Quero selecionar um desses arquivos e salvar em uma pasta interna (Cesta).

Aqui está quando eu selecionar um item dessa minha *listView*, eu pego a posição do item, porém a partir daqui, não sei como fazer para salvar esse item na pasta interna. Agradeço qualquer ajuda desde já.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int posicao, long l) {
                valor = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(posicao);
                File arquivo = (File) listView.getItemAtPosition(posicao);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você já consegue buscar o arquivo de origem.
Os próximo passo é somente realizar uma cópia do arquivo de origem.

Use a função abaixo passando os arquivos de origem e destino como parâmetros;

```
public static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src)) {
    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst)) {
        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Pode ver mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9293885/1469170).

Comment: Muito obrigado. Está ajudando bastante, mas como sou iniciante tenho um pouco de dificuldades, no caso a origem eu consigo passar por parâmetro, mas o destino eu criei assim  File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "Cesta");  dai quando eu vou passar isso por parâmetro, ele é do tipo java.lang.String, e estou passando por parâmetros do tipo java.io.File. Eu teria que converter isso para io.File, mas não sei como ainda.

Comment: Se seu arquivo `folder` está sendo criado corretamente isso não deveria acontecer.
Mas me parece que há um erro no seu código,  método `getExternalStorageDirectory()` retorna um objeto do tipo `File` segundo a própria referência do [android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()). Se quer buscar o endereço utilize: `getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` esse sim retornará o endereço. Lembre-se de tomar cuidado, pois não são todos dispositivos que possuem cartão SD.